# Refining div selected with jquery :contains() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, selector, contains

I have a html and script that pretty much look like this:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Post Content
  </div>
  <div>
    <p><strong>Related Topics</strong>
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>Topic list</li>
      <li>Topic list</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target only the Related Topics div and not the post content using this script:

```js
$("div:contains('Related Topics')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Currently that script underline everything including the post content.
Since the HTML is auto generated from RSS feed, I cannot add css class or edit it in any way. Any idea how can I achieve the desired result without modifying the HTML?

Comment: Don't forget your outer element is also a `<div>`, and that it contains "Related Topics". Use `div > div` or `div div` or some variation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` against each tags `html` whether its text is "Related Topics"

```
$("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).html() == "Related Topics";
}).css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/453/)

Comment: Perfect! thanks Anoop. One follow up question, how to select the parent of the returned div?

Comment: just use closest("div").css("text-decoration", "underline");

Comment: To select the parent, just use parent - `...}).parent().css(...` The parent in the case of the HTML you supplied is the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be slightly more specific in your selection. For instance

```
$("div").find("p:contains('Related Topics')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Would only underline the paragraph containing 'Related Topics'.

Comment: Thanks Jay! This works perfectly when the 'Related Topics' div parented by only one div. Unfortunately that's not always the case with the imported HTML..

Comment: You may have to, as other have said, just point to the next div in the sequence or some other element that is always there. If you showed us more of the markup that gets imported we could help you with a solid selector.

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the outermost div with your selector, it too contains the text "Related Topics". Try this:

```js
$("div").find("div:contains('Related Topics')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! This works perfectly when the 'Related Topics' div parented by only one div. Unfortunately that's not always the case with the imported HTML..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this spinet also.

$("div").find("div p:contains('Related Topics')").css("text-decoration", "underline");